# Order by Total Value on LinQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sql-order-by

I want to order my Linq GroupBy statement but the item that has the more Total Descending but i can't make it

**This is my LinQ**

```
foreach (var item in db
                    .Pos.Where(r => r.Fecha.Day <= today.Day)
                    .Select(g => new { Pdv = g.Pdv, Total = g.Total })
                    .GroupBy(l => l.Pdv)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(z => new { 
                         Punto_De_Venta=z.Key,
                         Total = String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}",
                                     Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0))
                    }))
{
    listadepuntos.Add(item.ToString());
}
var grupoPdv = new SelectList(listadepuntos.ToList());        
ViewBag.GroupS = grupoPdv;
```

**The Out put of my Linq Statement is :**

```
Punto_De_Venta = Central, Total = 42,143.00
Punto_De_Venta = Restaurante, Total = 189,949.00
Punto_De_Venta = Venta Moto, Total = 89,678.00
```

**And the Output im looking for is:**

```
Punto_De_Venta = Restaurante, Total = 189,949.00
Punto_De_Venta = Venta Moto, Total = 89,678.00
Punto_De_Venta = Central, Total = 42,143.00
```

How can i do this?? i cant find a way to make this

Comment: Sort the list before passing to SelectList `new SelectList(listadepuntos.OrderByDescending(l=>l.Total).ToList()); `

Comment: I tryed your approach but it give me an error saying 'String doesnt have a definition of Total' the error is on the Total part@Hari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List<>` does guarantee ordering, sort the List before passing to your `SelectList`

```
var grupoPdv = new SelectList(listadepuntos.OrderByDescending(l=>l.Total).ToList());
ViewBag.GroupS = grupoPdv;
```

**Another approach :**

Modify source query to return a sorted list.

```
var results = db.Pos.Where(r => r.Fecha.Day <= today.Day)
    .Select(g => new { Pdv = g.Pdv, Total = g.Total })
    .GroupBy(l => l.Pdv).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(z => new { Punto_De_Venta=z.Key, Total = String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => Total), 0))})
    .OrderByDescending(l=>l.Total)  
    .ToList();
```

Once you get the sorted list you can create your `SelectList` with sorted result.

```
var grupoPdv = new SelectList(result);
ViewBag.GroupS = grupoPdv;
```

Comment: I tryed your approach but it give me an error saying 'String doesnt have a definition of Total' the error is on the Total part @Hari Prasad

Comment: Modify this line `listadepuntos.Add(item.ToString());` to `listadepuntos.Add(item);`

Comment: doing that i get a 'has some not valid arguments' error, only converting item to string let me add it to 'listadepuntos'

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
foreach (var item in db.Pos.Where(r => r.Fecha.Day <= today.Day)
                           .Select(g => new { Pdv = g.Pdv, Total = g.Total })
                           .GroupBy(l => l.Pdv)
                           .AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(z => new { Punto_De_Venta = z.Key, Total = z.Sum(l => l.Total) })
                           .OrderByDescending(r => r.Total)
                           .Select(r => new { Punto_De_Venta = r.Punto_De_Venta, Total = String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", Decimal.Round(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0))})
{
    listadepuntos.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying the last 'z.' isnt on the actual context exactly at this part '(z.Sum(l => l.Total), 0))})'

Comment: That part was unchanged from your code - it simply removed the `string.format()`